# Using self-signed certificates in nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, client-certificates

I'm migrating services into a kubernetes cluster on minikube, these services require a self-signed certificate on load, accessing the service via NodePort works perfectly and demands the certificate in the browser (picture below), but accessing via the ingress host (the domain is modified locally in /etc/hosts) provides me with a Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate by Acme and skips my self-signed cert without any message.

The SSLs should be decrypted inside the app and not in the Ingress, and the tls-acme: "false" flag does not work and still gives me the fake cert

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    # decryption of tls occurs in the backend service
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: admin.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-service
                port:
                  number: 443
```

when signing in it should show the following before loading:
[image: Normal behaviour]

minikube version: v1.15.1

kubectl version: 1.19

using ingress-nginx 3.18.0

Comment: You may need to [enable ssl-passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough), which is disabled by default. This is required to enable passthrough backends in Ingress objects. Try enabling it and let me know if it works

Comment: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" exists in the ingress but it didn't work
I also added nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true" but still nothing..

Comment: Did you actualy check the link I gave you?

Comment: Yes, I did, but isn't the annotation in the ingress enough to change the value in the nginx controller? I will try to add it manually

Comment: From docs: `The --enable-ssl-passthrough flag enables the SSL Passthrough feature, which is disabled by default`. This means that annotation will work as soon as you enable this feature. (At least this is how understand it)

Comment: Also here is a note: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough: `Note: SSL Passthrough is disabled by default and requires starting the controller with the --enable-ssl-passthrough flag.`

Comment: OK, So i've added the flag to the nginx deployment, and nginx.conf has the flag "is_ssl_passthrough_enabled = true"
I tried to add this combination of annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" , but still the website is not secure and it does not behave like it would without ingress

Comment: I saw you created a github issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6722 I will leave this link here. Maybe it will help somebody one day. Anyway, I tried replicating your issues and can confirm that this is not working for me either.

Comment: Did you try to replicate it with Minikube? I will update if a solution is found

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a bug on Minikube, and also having to [enable ssl passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough) in the nginx controller (in addition to the annotation) with the flag `--enable-ssl-passthrough=true`.

I was doing all my cluster testing on a Minikube cluster version v1.15.1 with kubernetes v1.19.4 where ssl passthrough failed, and after following the guidance in the [ingress-nginx GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6722), I discovered that the issue didn't replicate in kind, so I tried deploying my app on a new AWS cluster (k8 version 1.18) and everything worked great.